# How to get errors that happens on your app from other devices?

Tags: java, android

i have made a card game app for android.
In my device and the emulators everything looks good when tested both local and with my remote server.

But on my play console i get some errors (4-3 in total) that affect 1 or 2 active user and i don't know if all errors are reported in the console or just some.

The problem is that i can't simulate those error and i need to get some more informations from the crashed app, i have thought to catch the errors and send them to my Server (both exemptions and my own data that will save on app before crash).

Is there another easier way to do that?

MORE INFO:
most errors appear when something went wrong at sending a message to server and to other clients and next client receive a null or something else, so all this errors happens in a try catch block when trying to listen from server. For example i was doing a String to double parse but a report on play console said tha an error was occur when parsing.

Comment: To get detailed stack trace use Firebase Crash Reporting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/).

Comment: if i have a String before the error can i get after the crash with the exception message?

Comment: Yep you can tweak the crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses crash reporting tools like firebaseCrash analytics, Fabric or ACRA library for crash reporting

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Crash reporting services like **Fabric** they have an android studio plugin which will make the integration easier. Fabric will send details with line number about the crash in the registered email. I'm using fabric for error reporting in my apps. see [Fabric.io](https://fabric.io/)